# Query function not being fired when called

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have a Jquery function to delete a row in an HTML table, it  looks like this;

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $("#thisNet td a.delete").click(function() {

        if (confirm("Are you sure you want to delete this row?")) {

            var id = $(this).parent().parent().attr('id');
            var data =  'id=' + id ;
            var parent = $(this).parent().parent();

            $.ajax({
                   type: "POST",
                   url: "delete-row.php",
                   data: data,
                   cache: false,
                   success: function()
                   {
                        parent.fadeOut('slow', function() {$(this).remove();});
                   }
             });                
        }
    });
});
```

I don't know if it works or not because when I click the button I never get into the function. The delete item to click is in a table  created by PHP/MySQL. I followed the tutorial here; https://sarfraznawaz.wordpress.com/2009/09/14/deleting-table-rows-using-jquery-and-php/ to create the delete function. I'm guessing the reason it doesn't fire has to do with timing. The $(document).ready(function() already thinks the page is done loading before the table is created..but I don't know how to overcome this problem.

The page is here; http://kcmecc.org/RaspPi/ once you access it use the drop down to select Net #1. The delete column is the last one with the red x.

Comment: your link is not working

Comment: `var parent = $(this).parent().parent();` -> yuck, use closest instead.http://api.jquery.com/closest/

Comment: You should run the $("#thisNet td a.delete").click(...) after the table has loaded to be able to listen to the click.

Comment: DOM issue because you want to be fancy, `"#thisNet td a.delete"` does not exist when the dom first loads.

Comment: Where is the code for your table creation and where's the markup for your actual table? If it's done in PHP, I don't see why it wouldn't already exist on the page by document ready. If it's created dynamically through javascript, that's a different story.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your delete button doesn't exist on document ready. You need to use [`.on`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) to delegate the event to an ancestor element when dynamically adding elements...

`$(document).on('click', '#thisNet td a.delete', function() {`

Comment: You're kind of just assuming here. For all you know, his table doesn't even have the right ID.

Comment: No i'm not. Look at his page (remove index.html from the url). He is retrieving the table html with an ajax call and adding it to the DOM.

Comment: His page just gives me a 404.

Comment: Read my previous comment again.

Comment: It looks like @Sexy Turnip is on the right track. I can now delete it from the table on the page. I need to get the MySQL part working now. Much easier for me. Thank you so much for the help.